# Configure Timestamp for AXION gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, axion-release-plugin

I am using axion of creating the release build. I am having multiple submodule gradle project. When I am building it : for each submodule jar name is having different timestamp and which is correct.

**I am trying to use the same timestamp for all jar names**. I went through the axion doc but nothings related to name configuration mentioned?